# VMware: Best way to assign static IP and DNS entries for guest machines?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, command-line

I'm looking for a scriptable solution for assigning a static IP address and DNS entries for VMware guest machines. There is a pool of IP addresses we allocate for internal use, so I need to be able to set specific IP addresses for each machine.

Is there any easy way to do this using commandline tools?

Answer (score 0):

Make a batch file and use `wmic` to apply the changes:

```
wmic nicconfig where description="VMWare NIC..." call enablestatic ("192.168.1.100"),("255.255.255.0")
wmic nicconfig where description="VMWare NIC..." call enabledns ("8.8.8.8")
```